# How to edit a QGIS plugin GUI?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I have inherited a QGIS system from a former employee and my predecessor built a custom plugin for it. I now need to remove a single checkbox option completely from the UI for this plugin. Is there a simple way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. There should be a .ui file which can be edited using Qt Designer. It will allow you to remove the checkbox. Then you will need to make sure to remove the references to this checkbox in the code.

Depending on how the user interface is instantiated, you'll also have to recompile the .ui file. This is done on the command line. On Windows, I suggest using the OSGeo4W Shell. Navigate to the plugin folder and run:

```
pyuic4 -o ui_file_name.py ui_file_name.ui
```